# dc.js - rectangular brush for heat map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js

I'm looking to use a dc.js heat map like [this](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heat.html), but with a rectangular brush like implemented in the [scatter plot](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-brushing.html). Is there an easy(-ish) way to achieve this w/o having to dabble with [d3-brush](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush) myself?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation on whether this is possible out of the box, so I suspect not. The default row-/column-/cell-clicking works just fine, but is imo not efficient (in terms of user effort) enough for selecting cells in a larger matrix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - that functionality is not currently included in the heatmap.

It would be really nice to add it, but it's probably a bit of work.

In the meantime, if you're willing to fiddle a bit with the parameters, you can get a decent approximation using the scatter plot, since it allows you to change the size and shape of the dots.

I took the [heatmap filtering example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heatmap-filtering.html), swapped a `scatterPlot` for the `heatmap`, changed a few parameters, and got something that works reasonably well:

[image: heatmap simulated with scatter plot]

First, we can set the width and height to accommodate "dots" of size 15x15, just as we do in the heatmap example - except we are stuck with square dots if we use a scatterplot:

```
        .width(12 * 15 + 40)
        .height(27 * 15 + 20)
        .margins({left: 40, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20})
```

The margins are for the axis text.

Next, we set the x domain to fit around dots that will be centered on their values:

```
        .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([-0.5,11.5]))
        .yAxisPadding(0.5)
```

(Not sure why `elasticY` works but `elasticX` doesn't... only so much digging you can do at one time.)

Next, we can set the excluded radius to the same as the normal radius, and use grey for excluded dots:

```
        .symbol(d3.symbolSquare)
        .excludedSize(15)
        .symbolSize(15)
        .excludedColor('#ccc')
```

There are a few different ways you could indicate what's filtered in/out - take a look at [the scatterPlot docs](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.scatterPlot.html) for other ideas. For example you could also use [`excludedOpacity`](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.scatterPlot.html#excludedOpacity__anchor). But I find opacity kind of confusing for a heatmap because fading makes it look like it just has a different value rather than being excluded entirely. Season to taste!

Finally, the scatter plot uses "real" d3 axes, so the Y axis needs to be configured to display numbers correctly:

```
            heatmapChart.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('.4'))
```

Overall, I was surprised how easy this was, since they take the same data format and have most of the same parameters.

[Example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/bs9to0hd/8/)

Comment: Great answer as always, Gordon. I'll "fake" the heatmap like this. Thanks a lot!